# Mobile Safari YouTube IFRAME event issue

Tags: youtube, touch, mobile-safari

Context:

I have a container element that is 100% the width and height of the iPad Mobile Safari window and inside of that I have a YouTube IFRAME to embed the video (100% width and height).

The issue is that I also have a close button anchored to the top right of the page. The close button has a higher Z Index than the iframe and has a click listener that alerts "foo" (no usable console.log on iOS6 without web debugging).

Before the Play button in the IFRAME is pressed the callback for the close button is called when it's tapped. After the play button in the IFRAME is pressed the close button callback is never called, instead the video controls are toggled in the IFRAME.

This issue does not exist on Google Chrome on a Nexus 7, just Mobile Safari on iPad.

Links:
http://pastie.org/8030167

http://jsfiddle.net/amyMM/

```
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

alert("foo")

e.preventDefault()
e.stopPropagation()

return false
})
```

**Further information:**

After adding listeners on the window for touchstart, touchmove and touchend, all of these events fail to fire anywhere on the page until the video has finished playing, after which the events fire only on the close button.

Comment: I am also having this issue. I attached an event listener to the window and logged every `target.target`. I find that the target sometimes changes after I change the `translate3d` property.